# Want to override Magento 2 Contact Form Block

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks

I have created a custom module app/code/Demo/Mymodule and I want to override Contact Form Block.

After configuration and registration of module, I have Created di.xml in app/code/Demo/Mymodule/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" type="Demo\Mymodule\Block\ContactForm" />
</config>
```

Then, I have created ContactForm.php in app/code/Demo/Mymodule/Block

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Mymodule\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class ContactForm extends \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm{
public function getFormAction()    {
echo "Demo Text";
return $this->getUrl('contact/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
}
}
```

I have run all the commands like:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But, I am not getting output (Demo Text) on contact page

Comment: What you want to change in your custom block?

Comment: Right now, I just want to add text (Demo Text) which I have written in ContactForm.php. I just want to check whether the block is overridden or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code, it's working

You can see "**Demo Text**" before in form action. You can view it by inspect element.

Contact form action like this in inspect element

```
<form class="form contact" action="Demo Texthttp://
```

Also you can test it by write **exit**; just after "`Demo Text`" in your custom block.

```
public function getFormAction()    {
echo "Demo Text";
exit;
return $this->getUrl('contact/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
}
```

**If you show text on contact form, see below solution for it**

Copy file from

```
vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

and put it to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml
```

You can change contact us form from this file, write a code as per you need.

Comment: Where to write exit? I can't get it

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Actually I want to show text on contact form

Comment: No need to modify core block. You can write directly in form.phtml file.

Comment: If I want to show text on contact form using ContactForm.php (Block), then how can I do that?

Comment: You have to create your custom function and call it to form.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63488/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-muneeb-syed).