# Magento 2: Problem overriding product/view/form.phtml in custom module

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I tried using this in my catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <!-- <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">

        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="shopmethtempindex" xsi:type="string">Interjar_ConfigurableChildVisibility::product/view/form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>       
            </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer> -->

    <!-- <referenceContainer name="content"> 
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="shopmethtempindex" xsi:type="string">Interjar_ConfigurableChildVisibility::product/view/form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer> -->

    <referenceContainer name="content">                
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">

            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Interjar_ConfigurableChildVisibility::product/view/form.phtml">
            </block>
            
   
        </referenceContainer>
        
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: override in theme or custom module ??

Comment: override in custom module

Answer (score 0):

templates are a Ui components not templates
you can also review this
[Want to override Magento 2 Contact Form Block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188356/want-to-override-magento-2-contact-form-block)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I am trying to override the core file which is located in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml